# Read until end of channel in Go

Tags: go, idioms, channel

The producer fills up the channel with some values and closes it.
On the consumer side I want to add up all the values and leave the loop at the end.  My solution looks like:

```
total := 0
for {
    v, ok := <- ch
    if !ok { break }
    total += v
}
```

Is there any more elegant way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A for/range loop will work, as long as the producer closes the channel.

```
total := 0

for v := range ch {
    total += v
}
```

Play: http://play.golang.org/p/cWcA57dnLC